# Why doesn't windows authentication work with host alias'?

Tags: windows, network-shares, authentication, ntlm

Normally accessing a Windows share is accomplished using a UNC path e.g. \\server\share where "server" is the real hostname of the Windows machine. \\server.domain.com\share also works.

However access does not appear to work using host alias'. For example if you put this in the hostile:

```
192.168.1.5   server   server-alias
```

Both will be pingable, however share access fails using \\server-alias\share.

I'm aware SMB access uses NTLM authentication, I suppose kerberos in a domain environment. So I suspect NTLM might not support alias' like this. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, NTLM got a set list of host-names it will authenticate with.
When just creating an alias like that, without updating it on the "server side" the auth will fail.

I found two relating articles regarding a few windows flavors :-)

[Link 1 - Regarding IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)

[Link 2 - Regarding access on 2003 server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642)

As it seems both need the server-side to be updated to work, I believe you're correct in assuming this is due to the nature of NTLM.

Comment: The first link didn't work. I added the alias to the server host file but that didn't work. I guess host alias' are not supported by NTLM.

Comment: Looks like aliases are a bit unreliable when it comes to NTLM yes. The above was just a few examples, and not necessarily the -solution- you're looking for.